# Windows c drive ran eraser

Tags: windows, disk-space

I installed eraser free file shredder and by mistake I created a task with C: disk partition and did click start task. What happened next was my PC ran into blue screen code storage exception.

After this I could and can't boot getting message pxe mof: can't boot. I used my recovery Windows installer tried to fix start up and it didn't work.

I used `cmd` to list disks and C: had only 9GB free while before this problem it was something like 600GB free.

So I started `chkdsk` on C with /r /f and it is saying bad links in lost chain at cluster X corrected.

Do you think I will be able to use the disk again without formatting Windows? The data I had on my disk was important and I have no back up of it since it was recent.

It's a laptop, I have a Windows setup USB (Windows 10), I do not have a restore point.

Comment: You have backups right?

Comment: Can you also provide a link to the tool you used? This is sounding very much like you have erased your entire drive.

Comment: https://eraser.heidi.ie/

Comment: Chkdsk finished and said it freed 660gb from disk... Now its verifying free space

Comment: If you have a second PC, I would put the drive into that as a secondary drive to see if you can recover anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I'm assuming that the tool you used is a secure deletion tool that overwrites all data on a disk to make it harder to recover. I couldn't find a lot of information about it. If this assumption is wrong please let me know.

I'm pretty sure you've accidentally erased your C partition using a software that performs secure deletions. Windows probably ran into an issue (and BSOD'd) when the eraser started touching Windows files.

I would recommend any of the following solutions:

1. re-installing Windows and losing access to any files that weren't removed yet, or connecting the hard drive to another computer to see if you can recover any files.
2. connecting the hard drive to another computer and attempting to recover any files that might not have been deleted yet.
3. Booting from a Linux live USB and using a recovery tool such as `ntfsundelete` to attempt to recover as many files as possible. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13706/recover-deleted-files-on-an-ntfs-hard-drive-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/)'s a guide.